# Reading through Tapes - JCL

Tags: jcl

We currently backup some of our data to tapes (virtual, not physical) and I am needing to read and pull information from those tapes. Currently we are using JCL with a DD statement for each Vol/Ser that looks like:

```
//VOLSERO  DD DSN=DWP.PROD.****.TAPE,
//            DISP=SHR,                          
//            UNIT=CCLOCAL,                      
//            VOL=SER=(R94188)                   
//*                                              
//         DD DSN=DWP.PROD.****.TAPE,
//            DISP=SHR,                          
//            UNIT=CCLOCAL,                      
//            VOL=SER=(R94438)
```

Each week we drop 1 tape and add a new one as we are backing up new records. Is it possible to read through all of the tapes for that dataset without entering the Vol/Ser or will every tape require it's own DD statement?

Comment: Are these datasets cataloged?  Does the "****" mask in the sample you provided uniquely identify the dataset?  Are these datasets SMS managed?  Are you allowed to change the job(s) that create these datasets?

Comment: yes, the "****" mask is uniquely identified datasets and the JCL that's right's it looks as such:
    //DWPSTRNU DD DSN=DWP.PROD.SEND.****(+1),                   
    //            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,CATLG),                              
    //            MGMTCLAS=#STNDARD,                                   
    //            SPACE=(350,(50,5),RLSE),AVGREC=K,                    
    //            DCB(****.DSCB,RECFM=FB,LRECL=350,BLKSIZE=0,DSORG=PS)

Comment: From the +1 you are using a GDG. Talk to your Storage people.

Answer (score 2):

You indicate the datasets are cataloged, so you shouldn't need to specify the volume serial number.

As @BillWoodger indicates in his comment, talk to your storage people.  Coding the `DEFER` subparameter of the `UNIT` option might be beneficial, as may `UNIT=AFF`.  Your storage people, and possibly your production control people, will know how they want it done in your shop.

You indicate the datasets are part of a `GDG`, so to access the most recent 3 generations you should be able to code...

```
//VOLSERO  DD DSN=DWP.PROD.SEND.****(0),
//            DISP=SHR
//         DD DSN=DWP.PROD.SEND.****(-1),
//            DISP=SHR
//         DD DSN=DWP.PROD.SEND.****(-2),
//            DISP=SHR
```

If you want to access *all* extant generations, and it sounds like you do, you should be able to code...

```
//VOLSERO  DD DSN=DWP.PROD.SEND.****,
//            DISP=SHR
```

...and be aware of the `GDGORDER` parameter if you want the datasets in ascending chronological creation order.

Again, talk to your storage and production control people.  There's often a difference between what's possible, what's acceptable, and what's optimal.